# Is an API call to Magento an observable event?

Tags: php, api, magento, events, soap

My instance of Magento is integrated with an ERP that updates Magento's stock quantities via the catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate API call (from the ERP) which runs hourly.

I have some outgoing API calls from Magento that happen when a product is saved. It appears that Magento is not seeing the quantity update API call from the ERP as a product save. I want to capture that API quantity update as a save event, so that the other outgoing API calls will fire on the products with updated quantities.

Is there a way to set up an observer to catch the catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate call as a save event on the products whose quantities are actually updated?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it might help anyways. I'm running into a related issue where a web service is called to update a product and the observer "catalog_product_save_after" is being triggered when we don't want it to. So observers should work on API calls.